# rails generate bootstrap layout with bootstrap-sass instead of twitter-bootstrap-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap-rails, bootstrap-sass

I had to choose from `bootstrap-sass` and `twitter-bootstrap-rails` and I've opted for the first as per suggestions on the web.

However, I see that `twitter-bootstrap-rails` gem has some generators for application layout. Like,

```
rails g bootstrap:layout application fixed
rails g bootstrap:themed Posts
```

Which I find very good for kick-starting a project. But I don't find similar generators available in the `bootstrap-sass` gem. Running the command:

```
rails generate
```

doesn't show any generators like the previous ones.

Is there any way to have those layout using `bootstrap-sass` instead of using `twitter-bootstrap-rails`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using this gem, although I am unaware of generators for it.

I found a gem on GitHub which you might find useful:

https://github.com/decioferreira/bootstrap-generators

Alternatiely, you may simply define a new custom.css.scss file and start playing with the css of the whole app. And don't forget to add the bootstrap imports to your files!

Answer (score 7):

There you can find a good way to generate theme for bootstrap-sass:

https://github.com/doabit/bootstrap-sass-extras

Basically you just:

```
 rails g scaffold Post title:string description:text
 rake db:migrate
 rails g bootstrap:themed Posts
```

Answer (score 0):

There are also these (lesser known but probably worth a try) gems:

https://github.com/thrivesmart/bootscaf

https://github.com/leandroo/flexi_generators